# Why:$\left({e^{ix}}\right)^{n－2k}＝\cos((n－2k)x)$

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

**proplem**
Prove that:$$\cos^n (x)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}\cos((n-2k)x)$$

This propelm In book : [Sums and product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0999342819)
Proplem 3.2

This answer this in Book:
[image: answerThe proplem]

My question:
Why:$$\left({e^{ix}}\right)^{n－2k}＝\cos((n－2k)x)$$

I know that:$$\left({e^{ix}}\right)^{n－2k}＝\cos((n－2k)x)+i\sin((n－2k)x)$$

Comment: It's because if you break down that sum and you have the sum of sin terms, the sin terms will eventually cancel out itself. You may need to use the symmetry of "a choose b" and that sin(-x)=-sin(x). But of course, this is expected as it is real.

Comment: @copper.hat  I D'ont Understand , Why Take the real part

Comment: @UnsinkableSam If you could edit a full answer explaining why this is the case I would be happy to do so.

Comment: @Mostafa The left hand side is real, so the right hand side much be also. The real part of $e^{ix}$ is $\cos x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the case that $n$ is odd (for the other case it's really similar, see if you can imitate this argument). So let's say $n=2l+1$. I want to show $$\sum_{k=0}^{2l+1} {2l+ 1\choose k} \sin((2l+1-2k)x)=0.$$

So let's open it up, it would be $${2l+ 1\choose 0} \sin((2l+1)x)+{2l+ 1\choose 1} \sin((2l-1)x)+\cdots {2l+ 1\choose 2l} \sin((-2l+1)x)+ {2l+ 1\choose 2l+1} \sin(-(2l+1)x).$$

You see the first term cancels out the last term, second cancels out the second to last etc... so these terms pair up perfectly. Thus the sum is $0$, thus the sin terms that you were worrying about is actually $0$. So the writer didnt bother writing it down.

Answer (score 1):

OP mistook that $\left({e^{ix}}\right)^{n－2k}＝\cos((n－2k)x)$, which is definitely wrong and can be corrected as

$$ \Re [\left({e^{ix}}\right)^{n－2k}\,]＝\cos((n－2k)x)$$
The proof could be presented as below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos ^n x= & \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) e^{i(n-2 k) x} \\
= & \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) \cos ((n-2 k) x) +\frac{1}{2^n} i \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) \sin ((n-2 k) x)
\end{aligned} 
$$

Comparing the real part of the equation, we have
$$
\cos ^n x=\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) \cos ((n-2 k) x)
$$

---

By the way, comparing the imaginary part yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) \sin ((n-2 k) x)=0
$$